# Using sed to replace a version number in a file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I need to update a version number in a file. In the file there is one line that contains the semantic-version number like this:

```
foo.bar.blah.blub#10.6.1
```

Now I want to look for the prefix "blah.blub" to identify the right line and replace the version number.

I got the following that obviously doesn't work:

```
sed -i -e 's/^blah.blub#\d\.\d\.\d$/blah.blub'${VERSION}/$ README.MD
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sed uses Basic Regular Expressions by default, and most implementations (including the GNU one which you seem to be using) don't understand `\d`. Also, your line doesn't start with `blah.blub`, so the `^` means it will never match. And various other issues.

This should do what you need though:

```
sed -i -E "/blah\.blub#/s/#.*/#$VERSION/" README.MD
```

That will replace the text after a `#` with the contents of `$VERSION`, but only if this line contains `blah.blub`. Now, whether that is specific enough to deal with your data, I have no idea, since you have only shown us that one line.

Comment: @stéphane does that mean there are some sed implementations whose BRE flavor includes `\d`?

Comment: ast-open's `sed` supports it. Since the behaviour is otherwise unspecified by POSIX, it's a sensible thing to do for `sed` implementations. GNU `sed` added `\s` which is very similar, they might add `\d` in the future.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I see, thanks! And what was it that tipped you off that the OP was using GNU sed? I don't see any GNUisms here, what am I missing?

Comment: `sed -i` is a GNU extension, though it's true there are few more that support it these days (busybox, netbsd, openbsd, ast-open). That was more a guess.

Answer (score 2):

`-i` and `\d` are `perl` features. There are `sed` implementations where either or both (like ast-open's) features have been added, but in any case, neither feature is in the standard specification of the `sed` command and that's not portable.

Here, you might as well use the real thing:

```
export VERSION
perl -pi -e 's/^([\w.]*\.)?blah\.blub#\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/$ENV{VERSION}/' README.MD
```

Here allowing an optional sequence of 0 or more *word* characters or dots, ended with a dot before the `blah.bluh`, and allowing more that one digit in each of the 3 components of the original version number.

We're also passing the new version string via an environment variable rather than in the code expression which makes it safer (avoids the arbitrary code injection vulnerability) and more reliable (allows any character or even byte value in the text of the new version).